# Android gradle trouble after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

I used to have an older version of Android Studio (Not entirely sure which one, it was from a few months ago / maybe last year) and everything was working great. It was some kind of RC version, maybe RC-2?

Anyway, last week I updated to the latest version, v1.4, and now gradle and everything else is completely broken. NO CODE HAS CHANGED.

Here's my old gradle file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This file gives the error `"You must use a newer version of the Android Gradle plugin. The minimum supported version is 1.0.0 and the recommended version is 1.3.0".`

So, when I change gradle to 1.3.0 (or 1.0.0) that error disappears, but is replaced with 101 errors that all look like this:

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

For example, the above error is referencing an Android file called ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml which is not in my project at all. It's a standard Android file with content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-ldltr-v21/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined"/>
</resources>
```

Again. NONE OF MY CODE HAS CHANGED and suddenly everything is broken. I've also tried cleaning/buildling, invalidating cache and restarting, and reverting to my latest commit / rebuilding. Nothing has worked; how can I fix this?

Comment: check your `compileSdkVersion 21`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your build.gradle files.

**Use the last stable plugin: 1.3.1**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

**Update your gradle version**, changing the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

**Then check your dependencies:**

**AppCompat builds themes that require the APIs with the same level to compile your application.**

It means that

```
  //You have to use compileSdkVersion=23
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'


  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

Comment: I'm targeting SDK 19, and now I'm getting a new error:

6:51:35 PM Error running build: Target module is undefined

Are these related?

Comment: Also, after restart now (I've done this many times before) Android Studio warned me that this project is not using Gradle.... WHAT!! haha I don't know what the heck hapened